# How to show all rows of a filter containing Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas

in a given dataframe in pandas, is there a way to see all the Booleans present in `filt` in the code below:

```
filt = dataframe['tag1'] =='ABC'
filt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR

It's possible. I think you should use indexing, it's extensively described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). To be more specific you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).
Code should look like this

```py
filt = df[df.loc[:,"tag1"] == 'ABC]
```

## Now what actually happens here

`df.loc[:,"tag1"]`  returns all rows `:` character, but limits columns to just "tag1". Next `df.loc[:,"tag1"] == 'ABC` comperes returned rows with value "ABC", as the result grid of True/False will be created. True row was equal to "ABC" etc. Now the grand final. Whenever you pass grid of logical values to an dataframe they are treated as indicators whether or not to include the result. So let's say value at [0,0] in passed grid is True, therefore it will be included in the result.
I understand it's hard to wrap one's head around this concept but once you get it it's super useful. The best is to just play around with this `iloc[]` and `loc[]` functions.